# Using a variable in parameters to query data from sqlite database in a node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

So i'm making a discord bot with discord.js and not too sure how to go about this, have looked around for a while.

```
    var server = member.guild.id;
    db.all("SELECT channelMessage FROM userHelp WHERE serverId = server", function(err, rows){
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                console.log("Message is " + channelMessage);
            })
        });
```

I know that this won't really work, but it's essentially what I'm aiming for, with the "WHERE" clause in line 2 using the previously defined variable as its parameter. 
I'm pretty inexperienced to be honest, so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Read [this](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/) Tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the `server` variable doesn't come from user input, you can interpolate it into your query string. In newer versions of javascript (es2015 and above, I believe), you should be able to just do:

```
var server = member.guild.id;

db.all(`SELECT channelMessage FROM userHelp WHERE serverId = ${server}`, ...)
```

Comment: **Important note for future readers:** The very first statement made in this answer is *critical*. This code is potentially open to SQL injection if you don't have full control over the `server` variable value. The problem of SQL injection is outside the scope of the question asked above, and so only casually alluded to in the first statement of this answer. This is a demonstration of string interpolation, *not* query parameters. (This note was left here because another answer attempted to link to this one as an example of how to use query parameters, which this answer does not demonstrate.)