# What is the correct syntax for replacements within a SQL string

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I am attempting to do a basic search in my sqlite3 database with this JavaScript:

```
function search(query) {
  let sql = `SELECT * from tracks WHERE title LIKE '%${query}%'`

  db.sqlite.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
    console.log(rows)
  })
}
```

This works but is vulnerable to SQL injection. I am trying to get the sqlite replacements parameter to work but I cannot get the syntax right. Sqlite doesn't want to replace anything within the string literal.

```
// throws SQLITE_RANGE error
let sql = `SELECT * from tracks WHERE title LIKE '%$query%'`
db.sqlite.all(sql, {$query: query}, (err, rows) => {})
```

What is the correct way to write this so that it's not vulernable to SQL injection?

Comment: My first search attempt landed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997182/using-a-variable-in-parameters-to-query-data-from-sqlite-database-in-a-node-js-a where the solution can be found ... LIKE ${query} ... what about searching first before asking here a question ;-)?

Comment: Don't put the qoutes and percent signs around the name of your parameter, eg `'%$query%'` should just be `$query`, [sqlite module docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback)

Comment: @BitLauncher your link only covers safe input, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PatrickEvans That does work, but how do I make it work with %'s?

Comment: They would need to be part of the value in `query` itself, eg `query = '%yourvalue%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
let sql = `SELECT * from tracks WHERE title LIKE '%' || $query || '%'`
```

Answer (score 1):

What are these || for? SQLite specialty? Yes, it is a way to concatenate strings in SQL - I do not know any other DBMS that uses that. So this solution only works for SQLite, but AFAIK not for MySql, Oracle, Transact SQL, ... it is not standard SQL.

I think it is hard to know this trick with ||.
There is a IMHO more understandable approach, that every developer easy understands:

I would first change the value of the variable, then overgive it as a parameter to the query, like that the code should be readable - forgive me any oversight, because I am not a Javascript crack:

```
function search(query) {
  let likePattern = `%${query}%` // or in the very old days = '%' + query + '%'
  let sql = `SELECT * from tracks WHERE title LIKE $likePattern`

  db.sqlite.all(sql, {$likePattern: likePattern}, (err, rows) => {})
}
```

PS: Someone had this idea already too in the comments of the question, so if anyone upvotes this, then upvote the others comment too.